# Create a tag on each ec2 instance if it does not exist. Update tag with new value if it exists

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, boto3

I am trying to write a lambda that creates a tag of key 'MyID' and value of 'null'. The tag should be attached to each instance if the tag does not exist.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')

def handler(event,context):
    response = client.describe_instances()
    for reservation in response['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            instance.create_tags(Tags={'TagName': 'TagValue'})
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that should do it:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

def handler(event, context):

    # Get a list of instances
    response = client.describe_instances()

    # For each instance
    for reservation in response['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:

            # Extract existing tags
            tags = [tag['Key'] for tag in instance['Tags']]

            if 'MyID' not in tags:
                # Add a tag
                tag_response = client.create_tags(
                    Resources=[instance['InstanceId']],
                    Tags=[{'Key': 'MyID', 'Value': ''}]
                )
```

Comment: It worked for me as a command-line Python program (that is, outside of Lambda, by directly calling the `handler` function). What error are you getting in CloudWatch Logs? What do you mean by "This doesnt work"?

Comment: I would like to update tag value if tag exists and add tag if it doesnt exist then add the tag. Please see above "My attempt" section.

Comment: You can update a tag in exactly the same way as creating a tag. Simply create it and it will overwrite the existing value. In the above code, remote the `tags` line and the `if`.